# Two-Way Data Bind Not Applying with Controller - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, model-view-controller, 2-way-object-databinding

Good morning S.O. Gurus. Im having difficulty getting the two-way data binding working. The two way data binding is working in every other controller no problem, but this one is giving me a hard time. Can you assist please?

Controller / HTML:

```js
app.controller('search', function($scope, $http, $location) {
$scope.searchText = "";
 $scope.searchRun = function() {
  
  
  $scope.userQuery = "Last::Name+eq+"+$scope.searchText.replace(/ /g,"::")+"+or+First::Name+eq+"+$scope.searchText.replace(/ /g,"::")+"+or+Display::Name+eq+"+$scope.searchText.replace(/ /g,"::")+"+or+User::Login+eq+"+$scope.searchText.replace(/ /g,"::")+"+or+Manager::Display::Name+eq+"+$scope.searchText.replace(/ /g,"::");
  
  $http({
          method: 'GET',
         url: url
      })
      .then(function(res) {
   
   $scope.TransmutedUsers = {
    users: [
   
    ]
   };
   //Looping through users making a new object
   for(var i = 0; i < res.data.users.length; i++) {
    //console.log(res.data.users[i].id);
    var obj = {
     id: res.data.users[i].id
    };

    for(var x = 0; x < res.data.users[i].fields.length; x++) {
     //console.log(res.data.users[i].fields[x].name);
     var nameVar = res.data.users[i].fields[x].name.replace(/\s+/g, '');
     var valueVar = res.data.users[i].fields[x].value;
   
     obj[nameVar] = valueVar;  
   
    }
     $scope.TransmutedUsers.users.push(obj);
   }

  
   console.log($scope.TransmutedUsers.users);
   $scope.returnedUsersLength = $scope.TransmutedUsers.users.length;
   console.log($scope.returnedUsersLength);
   sessionStorage.setItem("searchActive", "true");
   
   
   if ($location.url() != "/search") {
    $location.url("/search");
   }
   
      });
 };
});
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top bg-color--brand-blue">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="/images/logo.png" class="logo" alt=""></a></li>
                <li><a href="/dashboard"><img src="/images/eAccess-logo-header.png" width="80" alt=""></a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="/profile">Welcome, <span>{{userName}}</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="/profile">Contact Help</a></li>
                <li><a href="/profile">Close Window</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="sub-header bg-color--light-grey">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="/newrequest" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Make a Request</a></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2 padding-right-none"><a href="/myprofile">My Profile</a></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2 padding-left-none"><a href="/directs">My Direct Reports</a></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2"><a href="/requests">My Requests</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <form ng-controller="search" ng-submit="searchRun();" class="pull-right">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search for people or requests" ng-model="searchText">
                    <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container" id="Search" ng-controller="search">
    <div class="row" id="SearchResultsUsers"> 
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <h1>Search Results: <i>{{searchText}}</i></h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" ng-repeat="user in TransmutedUsers.users">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
   <h3><i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i> <strong>{{user.FirstName}}</strong> {{user.LastName}} <small>({{user.UserLogin}})</small> <span>{{user.Role}}</span></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
   <p>{{user.JobTitle}}, <a href="mailto:{{user.Email}}" ng-show="user.Email">{{user.Email}}</a> <span ng-show="user.Phone">{{user.Phone}}</span> Reports to: {{user.ManagerDisplayName}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
   <p>Direct Reports: <span ng-show="user.DirectReports">{{user.DirectReports}}</span><span ng-show="!user.DirectReports">None</span></p>
    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

searchText does console.log but it does not bind to the {{searchText}} and the url does return the object successfully in the format specified, but that doesn't work with the {{}} either.

Using AngularJS 1.6

Please let me know if other information is required to help me solve this conundrum. Thank you all!

Comment: can you declare $scope.searchText outside the function?

Comment: That got rid of one error, but it still is not data-binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After declaring the $scope.searchText outside the search function,

you can force it by replacing the form :

```
<form ng-controller="search" ng-submit="searchRun();" class="pull-right">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search for people or requests" ng-model="searchText">
                    <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                </form>
```

with something easy like:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search for people or requests" ng-model="searchText">
 <button ng-click="searchRun(searchText)"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
```

and inside your search function:

```
$scope.searchRun = function(searchText) {
        $scope.searchText = searchText;
        ...rest of ur code
```

---

You can also try to debug this using this, in otder to see the changes made in the input directly in the html.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchText">
{{searchText}}
```

and in your controller declare outside the function

```
$scope.searchText = "";
```

Comment: This works if I put all of the controller's code into the parent controller. I cant seem to figure out why that controller is wrong, but at least its working in its parent. Thank you @Sletheren! I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: that's weird, cuz if you declare in the app.js this state linked to this controller it should work directly, without going to the parent controller, and happy I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is your use of two ngControllers.

[From Angularjs Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)

> When a Controller is attached to the DOM via the ng-controller directive, AngularJS will instantiate a new Controller object, using the specified Controller's constructor function. A new child scope will be created and made available as an injectable parameter to the Controller's constructor function as $scope.

So try declaring one `"search"` controller via ng-controller higher up on you DOM structure so the Divs share this instance of the controller. Unlike angularjs services controllers are not singletons.

I have created a plunker for you to show the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/J2Ho1uLq0jzuVLlX3BLG

Changing the scope on one controller does not change the scope on the other

Comment: This explains it! Thank you!